# How to make it where when a player is killed they are teleported somewhere

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a multiplayer minigame in Minecraft.

My goal is when the "killer" kills a player, that player will be teleported to a waiting room and once everyone is killed, they teleport back to the lobby. I've tried using tags, scores, scoreboards and even executes but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the player's spawnpoint to the waiting room where they are sent when they are killed.

```
/spawnpoint @a 1 2 3
```

Note that if you have beds inside your arena, you should put the command in a repeating command block so that the bed's spawn protocol is overriden.

Comment: Should the command be put in a repeating command block that is always active, to prevent players from using beds to respawn outside of the waiting room?

Comment: @fasterthanlight It depends on whether the OP is *using* beds in their map. If they are, a repeating command block would definitely be necessary. However, if there is no danger of players setting their own spawnpoints, you can reduce lag by running it only once at the beginning.